# Calculating MOE for derived proportion with tidycensus when MOE is NA

Tags: missing-data, census, tidycensus, proportions

Using ACS 5 year county-level estimates. Seeking to calculate the proportion of the county population over age 65.

```
my_variables <- c(total_pop = "B01003_001",
                  male_65_66 = "B01001_020",
                  male_66_69 = "B01001_021",
                  male_70_74 = "B01001_022",
                  male_75_79 = "B01001_023",
                  male_80_84 = "B01001_024", 
                  male_85_over = "B01001_025",
                  female_65_66 = "B01001_044",
                  female_66_69 = "B01001_045",
                  female_70_74 = "B01001_046",
                  female_75_79 = "B01001_047",
                  female_80_84 = "B01001_048", 
                  female_85_over = "B01001_049")

l_65 <- get_acs(geography = "county", 
                        variable = my_variables,
                        survey = "acs5",
                        year = 2021,
                        county = "Licking",
                        state = "OH",
                        geometry = FALSE) %>%
  summarise(over_65_est = sum(estimate[str_detect(variable, "^male|^female")]),
            over_65_moe = moe_sum(moe = moe[str_detect(variable, "^male|^female")], 
                                  estimate = estimate[str_detect(variable, "^male|^female")]),
            total = estimate[str_detect(variable, "^total")],
            total_moe = moe[str_detect(variable, "^total")],
            prop_65_est = over_65_est/total,
            prop_65_moe = moe_prop(over_65_est, total, over_65_moe, total_moe))
```

Census is returning NA for MOE of Total Population. Perhaps related to this issue

https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/technical-documentation/user-notes/2022-04.html

What is the recommended procedure for calculating the MOE of derived proportions when the denominator MOE is NA?